# Joomla 3 - Uploading components

Tags: php, joomla3.0

I will be building a component that allows me to override the user registration page. The question is, when I try to upload the custom component upon finishing the task, where does Joomla place the uploaded component? Will it be at the current templates folder(templates/mytemplate/html/) or in the components folder (root/components)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating a [new component](http://docs.joomla.org/Developing_a_Model-View-Controller_Component/3.1/Introduction) you have to define the path of your files in the [xml installation package](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Developing_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component#Pack_an_installation_zip_file).
All component files are placed at `components/*component_name/` folder.

If you just want to make a [template override](http://docs.joomla.org/Layout_Overrides_in_Joomla) of an **existing component** you have to copy the file that will be overriden from:

`components/*component_name/views/*view_category/tmpl/*tmpl_name.php`

to:

`templates/*template_name/html/*component_name/*view_category/*tmpl_name.php`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I think I need to avoid the template override way because as part of the requirement, when the administrator changes the template in the future, the features must stay functional. In short, I do need a component override. Also, the directory you have mentioned: components/*component_name/, is this the core directory of Joomla?

Comment: In case you change template in the future you just have to copy the files from one template to the other, it's not a difficult procedure. Changing the files in components/*component_name/ is a very bad practice as every joomla update will remove your customization (if it is made in a core component) and put files back in the previous state.

Comment: You're right that it's very easy to change template, but when we turn this over to the client, they're the ones who will maintain, and changing templates might be an obstacle. You're also right that changing the components core files is a very bad practice. That's why I am asking that, if I upload a cloned and modified copy of a component, where does Joomla place it.

Comment: If you create a a modified version of component it would be placed in components/*modified_component_name/ folder.

Comment: So for example: I cloned com_users component, and uploaded a new one, say com_usersmodified, then this will be stored in components/com_usersmodified folder instead of inside the template?

Comment: That's right, joomla doesn't put anything in templates folder by default. All data are stored to the component folder and only if something is overridden for a specific template stored in templates folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61875/discussion-between-ju-chan-and-emmanuel).